# Android GridView populate from the bottom

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `GridView`, and I want items in the grid to start from bottom left and grow to top. Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

I tried using this attribute:

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

but it doesn't work! What can be done?

Comment: Solved ! Look at the comments below

Comment: Restructured the question for better understandability.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about **GridView**,

but  in a **GridLayout** when you set its **orientation** to vertical. each new view is added vertically.

**row count** limits the number of views per column.

Comment: Actually, i want to continue adding items horizontally  (left to right), but i need that populating start from the bottom.

Comment: just for clarification. if grid was 3X3, would the top row have items 7, 8, 9. Middle row would have items 4, 5, 6. And bottom row would have items 1, 2, 3?

Comment: ok i already figured it out. What u need are these settings in your grid view (StackFromBottom:true)(RotationY:180). then go to your layout that defines your item. set the root layout, usually linearlayout (RotationY:180)

Comment: That's perfect, just i changed (RotationY:180) to (RotationX:180), that's work perfectly for me ! Thank you a lot Bernardo